# Optimal regularization for non linear optimization

Tags: bayesian, optimization

What would be the optimal (Bayesian?) solution for
fitting a model $f(x)$ to data $h$, given the following assumptions:

- $h$ is a vector with $N$ elements
- $h$ has Gaussian noise with known covariance $\sigma_h I$
- $x$ is known to have an a-priori Gaussian distribution, with covariance $C_x$
- the first- and second-order derivatives of $f(x)$ are known

My understanding is that:

- The maximum likelihood solution is given by minimizing 
  $\sum_{i=1}^N (f(x,i)-h_i)^2$.
- The MAP estimate is given by: $\sum_{i=1}^N \frac{1}{\sigma_c}(f(x,i)-h_i)^2 + \lambda x^t C_x^{-1} x$

Both can be optimized using non-linear optimization techniques such as BFGS.
So the question comes down to:

Is there a way to determine the optimal value for $\lambda$ ?

Answer (score 2):

In all similar problems I dealt with there was no "optimal" value for regularisation coefficient.

And now it seems to me that the only solution in your case is using [Cross Validation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_%28statistics%29) procedure.

Answer (score 2):

The proper Bayesian solution would be to treat the regularisation parameter as a nuisance parameter and marginalise it out of the analysis, using an appropriate hyper-prior.  In may be possible to do this analytically, which I have found to be reasonably effective, see section 2 of my paper

G. C. Cawley and N. L. C. Talbot, Preventing over-fitting during model selection via Bayesian regularisation of the hyper-parameters, Journal of Machine Learning Research, volume 8, pages 841-861, April 2007 ([www](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume8/cawley07a/cawley07a.pdf))

Alternatively you could choose the regularisation parameter by maximising the Bayesian evidence for the model, which is a common approach in neural networks, see e.g. [this paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.33.1345).

Cross-validation is also a reasonable non-Bayesian approach as Dmitri suggests (+1).